# Example of usage for IVsProject.AddItem

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Anybody has example for `IVsProject.AddItem` till now I have done following but did not understand how to use `IVsProject.AddItem` and `msdn` does not have any example.

```
private void MenuItemCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   IVsSolution solutionService = GetService(typeof(SVsSolution)) as IVsSolution;
   // get all projects in solution
   IEnumHierarchies enumHierarchies = null;
   Guid guid = Guid.Empty;
   ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(solutionService.GetProjectEnum(
                                  (uint)__VSENUMPROJFLAGS.EPF_ALLINSOLUTION,
                                  ref guid,
                                  out enumHierarchies));
   //Loop all projects found
   if (enumHierarchies != null)
   {
      // Loop projects found
      IVsHierarchy[] hierarchy = new IVsHierarchy[1];
      uint fetched = 0;

      while (enumHierarchies.Next(1, hierarchy, out fetched) == VSConstants.S_OK
           && fetched == 1)
      {                   
         Guid projectGuid;
         ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(hierarchy[0].GetGuidProperty(
                                        VSConstants.VSITEMID_ROOT,
                                        (int)__VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_ProjectIDGuid,
                                        out projectGuid));
         IVsProject project = (IVsProject)hierarchy[0];
         project.AddItem(VSConstants.VSITEMID_ROOT,
                         VSADDITEMOPERATION.VSADDITEMOP_OPENFILE,
                         1,
                         ...)

      }
   }            
}
```

following is also not working using `DTE`

```
private void MenuItemCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //GemFireWizardForm form = new GemFireWizardForm();
   //form.ShowDialog();
   //Get the solution service

   IVsSolution solutionService = GetService(typeof(SVsSolution)) as IVsSolution;
   // get all projects in solution
   IEnumHierarchies enumHierarchies = null;
   Guid guid = Guid.Empty;
   ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(solutionService.GetProjectEnum(
                                  (uint)__VSENUMPROJFLAGS.EPF_ALLINSOLUTION,
                                  ref guid,
                                  out enumHierarchies));
   //Loop all projects found
   if (enumHierarchies != null)
   {
      // Loop projects found
      IVsHierarchy[] hierarchy = new IVsHierarchy[1];
      uint fetched = 0;
      Guid projectGuid = Guid.Empty;
      while (enumHierarchies.Next(1, hierarchy, out fetched) == VSConstants.S_OK
           && fetched == 1)
      {
         ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(hierarchy[0].GetGuidProperty(
                                        VSConstants.VSITEMID_ROOT,
                                        (int)__VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_ProjectIDGuid,
                                        out projectGuid));
      }

      IVsHierarchy ppHierarchy = null;
      IVsSolution solution = (IVsSolution)GetService(typeof(SVsSolution));
      Int32 result = solution.GetProjectOfGuid(ref projectGuid, out ppHierarchy);

      if (ppHierarchy != null && result == VSConstants.S_OK)
      {
         Object automationObject = null;
         ppHierarchy.GetProperty(VSConstants.VSITEMID_ROOT,
                                 (Int32)__VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_ExtObject,
                                 out automationObject);

         if (automationObject != null)
         {
            EnvDTE.SolutionClass sc = automationObject as EnvDTE.SolutionClass;
            EnvDTE.Projects projects = sc.Projects;
            EnvDTE.Project project = projects.Item(1);
            EnvDTE.ProjectItems pitems = project.ProjectItems;

            pitems.AddFromFileCopy(@"e:\avinash\test.cpp");
         }
      }
   }            
}
```

`sc` is coming as `null`

Comment: Are you developing this as part of an AddIn?

Comment: You sample code really helped me out regarding the `project.AddItem`, but you should not have cut it short as I had to work out the missing parameters.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to add files to the root of the current project, using this piece of code :

```js
string file = ... ; // Provide the absolute path of your file here
string[] files = new string[1] { file };
VSADDRESULT[] result = new VSADDRESULT[1];
proj.AddItem(
    VSConstants.VSITEMID_ROOT,
    VSADDITEMOPERATION.VSADDITEMOP_OPENFILE,
    file,
    1,
    files,
    IntPtr.Zero,
    result);
```

Unfortunately, using IVsProject.AddItem it seems impossible to add filters to a project, or to add files under a filter. Indeed, [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsproject.additem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) mentions about the parameter `itemidloc` :

> itemidLoc
>   Type: System.UInt32
>   [in] Identifier of the container folder for the item being added. Should be VSITEMID_ROOT or other valid item identifier. See the enumeration VSITEMID. **Note that this parameter is currently ignored because only adding items as children of a project node is supported.** Projects that support the notion of folders will want to add the items relative to itemidLoc.

Comment: Works for me as well but it would be nice to understand how to add file to non-root directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this does not work, but maybe you can try to use MPF or VSXtra(created by deep dive), they both help us easily manage HierachyNode.